# problem with allocating memory getting Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c

in the following code, I am trying to make a function makestudernts(). it takes in a string and makes the objects puts it into the array and returns it.

however, I'm getting the following error

a.out: malloc.c:2374: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct mallo
c_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+(
(2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

the only thing I was able to figure out was that
String str3 = malloc(sizeof(char)*i);
was the line that causes it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef char* String;
void stringMalloc(String str, int size);
String fileToString(FILE * file);
void freeString(String  str);
struct Point2D{
    double x;
    double y;
};
struct busRote{
    struct Point2D * point;
    String name;
};
struct Student{
    struct Point2D point;
    String name;
    struct busRote rote;
    int stop;
};
void setPoint(struct Point2D * i , double x, double y){
    (*i).x =x;
    (*i).y = y;
}
void* makestudernts(String str){
    String str1 = str;
    String str2 = strchr(str1, ' ' );
    int count = 0;
    while(strchr(str1, '\n') != NULL){
        count++;
        str1 = strchr(str1, '\n') +1;
    }
    struct Student * arr = malloc( sizeof(struct Student*) * count);
    str1 = str;
    str2 = strchr(str1, ' ' );
    
    for(int j = 0; j < count; j++){
        
        double x = strtod(str1, &str2);
        str1 = str2;
        str2 = strchr(str1, ' ' );
        double y = strtod(str1, &str2);
        str1 = str2;
        int i = 0;
        i = 5;
        i =  strlen(str2);
        if( (strchr(str2,  '\n') - str2) < i ){
            i= strchr(str2,  '\n') - str2;
        }
        
        str2 = strchr(str2,  '\n');
        String str3 = malloc(sizeof(char)*i);
        strncpy(str3, str1, i);
        str1 = str2;
        struct Point2D point;
        setPoint(&point, x,y);
        struct Student student;
        student.point = point;
        student.name = str3;
        arr[j] = student;
    }printf("%s", arr[0].name);
    return arr;
}
int main(int argi, String argv[]){
    if(argi <3){
        printf("not enof files");
    }else{
        FILE* studentFile;
        FILE* busFile;
        studentFile = fopen (argv[1], "r");
        busFile = fopen (argv[2], "r");
        if (studentFile == NULL || busFile == NULL){
            printf("files not found");
        }else{
            String studentString;
            String busString;
            studentString = fileToString(studentFile);
            busString = fileToString(busFile);
            struct Student * arr= makestudernts(studentString);
            
            freeString(studentString);
            freeString(busString);
            fclose(studentFile);
            fclose(busFile);
            
        }
    }
}
String fileToString(FILE * file){
    char ch = fgetc( file );
    int count = 0;
    while(ch != EOF){
        count++;
        ch = fgetc(file);
    }
    
    String string = malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
    rewind(file);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        string[i] = fgetc(file);
    }
    return string;
}
void freeString(String str){
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including a `main` function and everything else needed to compile and run the code without having to guess what to fill in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Student * arr = malloc( sizeof(struct Student*) * count);
```

You want space for `count` students but you only allocate space for `count` pointers.  Should be `sizeof(struct Student)`.

> the only thing I was able to figure out was that `String str3 = malloc(sizeof(char)*i);` was the line that causes it.

That might be where the error is signalled, but it's not the *cause*.  It's very common that when you overrun an allocated buffer, the error is detected the *next* time you call a `malloc`-related function, because you've overwritten some of malloc's internal data.  (Of course, many other symptoms are also possible: segfaults, data corruption, undefined behavior in general.)